# Trying to get authentication working in Ruby On rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms-authentication

I've tried the following ROR code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticated(params[:email], params[:password)
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user_id
      flash[:notice] = "Log In Complete"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid Email or Password"
      render 'create'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect-to root_url, :notice =>"Logged Out"
  end
end
```

But I get this error:

> I:/dev/abierto/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'
>   I:/dev/abierto/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>           redirect-to root_url, :notice =>"Logged Out"
>   I:/dev/abierto/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
>           redirect-to root_url, :notice =>"Logged Out"
>   I:/dev/abierto/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Can anybody help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you read the error log? did you try to understand it and change what it tells you is wrong? >> your user `params` is missing the end of the statement... just **read the error message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first:

```
user = User.authenticated(params[:email], params[:password**]**)
```

... but there may be more errors. Paste it with line numbers

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a ] on line 5, it should read:

```
user = User.authenticated(params[:email], params[:password])
```

also the `redirect-to` is wrong, it should be `redirect_to`

I'm not even sure on the `flash.now.alert`, perhaps should be `flash.now[:alert]`

Comment: Thanks just started messing around with web Development a about a week ago, these error messages are pretty cryptic to the uninitiated.